Updating items on sorted list: How affect pagination, items shown. Pros and Cons?
I have a website where people can save and edit documents. The account is usually limited to a single person, but some accounts are shared with someone else (like a family account).
I show the list of documents on pages with NEXT and PREVIOUS page buttons.
What should happen if items are deleted, added, or edited, changing what page it's on?
Gmail and Google Documents always keep the page up-to-date, as though you had just done the search. This causes items to shift, with some items being moved off the page. However, if you don't update the page with every edit, other weird things happen.
Gmail and Google Docs behavior:
Gmail sorts by date, descending. Here that's represented by letters, alphabetically.
Let's say it shows 5 items per page.
------- Delete item from current page  -----------------------
Page 1: B C D E F
Page 2: G H I J K

View page 1 (shows B-F)
Delete C
Auto-adds item to bottom so still showing 5  (B-G)
Next page now starts at H

------- Delete item from a previous page ----------------------------
Page 1: B C D E F
Page 2: G H I J K
Page 3: L M

View page 1
Click next page (page 2, showing G - K)
In another tab, delete B.
Page 2 auto-changes: G disappears from the top and L gets added to the bottom.
(It does this because G now becomes part of page 1's 5 items)

Thoughts, issues:

Can it be confusing that an item suddenly disappears from the page?
This could be even more confusing if the change was made by the other account user. You wouldn't know why things shifted and disappeared.
Technically, this would be more complicated to code. There may also be some efficiency cost, having to do a search query with every item change. Slow things down?

------- Add item to current or previous page ----------------------------------
Page 1: B C D E F
Page 2: G H I J K

View page 1 (B - F)
New item A gets added
Page now auto-shows A at the top and G gets shifted off the page.

Thoughts:

Same comment as for deletion.

------- Edit item's sorted parameter -----------------
(I tested Google Drive behavior, sorting alphabetically)
Items:  A B C D

View page 1 (A - D)
Edit B so it's now called Z.
Page auto-updates, Z moving to the end.
(Presumably, if I had more items, Z could completely move out of view.)

Thoughts:

I don't like this behavior. I want to go back to my list and see the item that I just edited. If it's gone, I'd wonder if I accidentally deleted it.

What are some alternates?
What are your thoughts?
------------ ALTERNATE METHOD ---

Don't change a page while viewing it, except to remove a deleted item.
But update pages when do previous/next.

Page 1: B C D E F
Page 2: G H I J K
Page 3: L M

View page 1 (Showing 5 items, B-F)
Delete B (Showing 4 items, C-F)
Click next. (Showing H - L)

Issue:

G was skipped! Would have to click back to Page 1 to see it.


On of the reasons why I prefer (smooth) scrolling over pagination. Deleting or adding items does not raise the question which pages the objects are assigned to; a scrolling list has a viewport on the current list, and there's only the question what happens when the first visible row is deleted.

I'll answer your question with the following wireframes. First, I think you should follow the approach you mentioned is already working in Gmail: the user should be able to delete an element from the view by selecting it and pushing up the following items from the list into the current view. This happens when you select all your emails and click delete. It gives feedback to the user that all the selected emails were deleted. By following this approach, you'll prevent the user from selecting element G (which is not in the current view) and deleting it, making it seem like nothing happened. Be aware that there are two main actions: one for groups, as mentioned earlier, and one for individual items where the user can click an ellipsis icon and select delete, causing that item to disappear from the view.


For creating an item, if you're at the top of the list, the creation task should indicate that item Z was created and give the user the option to check it with an alert. This adheres to the principle of always giving the user feedback on what's happening in the system.

